# :foo => self.controller_name.to_s + "_path" does not return the path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please look at the two examples below:

```
irb(#<ActionView::Base:0x2863d58>):030:0> paintings_path
=> "/some-nice-alias-path"

irb(#<ActionView::Base:0x2863d58>):029:0> self.controller_name.to_s + "_path"
=> "paintings_path"
```

How do I return the path instead of the string?  I need to call the controller path from my application helper.

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 send(self.controller_name.to_s + "_path")
```

if you don't use send on self, it goes to Kernel, which is what you want.  self might work though, depending on exact context.

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but something like:

```
method = self.controller_name.to_s + '_path'
self.send(method.to_sym)
```

will probably do the trick. The `send` method takes a symbol and executes the method matching that symbol on the target object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ActiveRecord instance to work with, perhaps `polymorhpic_path` will suit your needs.  Using routing-aware path generation methods is preferable to brittle string-modification operations.